# Show that Identity is closed but not continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, closed-graph

I'm trying to show the following

The operator Identity defined as
$$I:(C[0, 1], ||\cdot||_1) \rightarrow (C[0, 1], ||\cdot||_\infty)$$ 
is closed but not continuous. So $(C[0, 1], ||\cdot||_1)$ it's not complete.

I get stuck to prove that is closed. Is there any result which would help me to prove that?

To prove that is not continuous

Take $(f_n) \subset (C[0, 1], ||\cdot||_1)$ defined as
$$f_n(t) = \dfrac{1}{(1+t)^n}$$

We have that $||f_n||_1 \rightarrow 0$ however $||f_n||\infty \rightarrow 1$

Thank you for any help

Comment: What definition for a closed map are you using? What happens if you try to directly apply the definition?

Comment: $T:E\rightarrow F$ is closed when $(x_n) \subset E$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $Tx_n \rightarrow y$ is necessary $x \in D(T)$ and $y = Tx$, I can't figure out how to show if I take a sequence of functions $f_n$ in $(C[0,1], ||.||_1)$ such that $||f_n - f||_1 \rightarrow 0$ then $f$ is in $C[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n,f,g\in C[0,1]$ and assume $\|f_n-f\|_1\to 0$ and $\|If_n-g\|_\infty = \|f_n-g\|_\infty\to 0$, just as in the assumptions for the definitions of closedness (Note that $f,g$ are already in $C[0,1]$ by assumption!).

We have to show that $g=f$.

There are probably multiple ways to do this, here is one suggestion:

Because of $\|\cdot\|_1 \leq \|\cdot\|_\infty$ we have
$$
 \|f-g\|_1 \leq \|f_n-f\|_1+\|f_n-g\|_1\leq \|f_n-f\|_1+\|f_n-g\|_\infty \to 0.
$$
This implies that $\|f-g\|_1=0$ and hence $f=g$.

Comment: I want to prove if I take a sequence $f_n$ in $C[0,1]$ such that $||f_n - f||_1 \rightarrow 0$ and $||f_n - g||_\infty \rightarrow 0$ then $f \in C[0,1]$ and your prof you just assumed that.
Also, I didn't understand which norm you're using at last inequality.
Thank you

Comment: I corrected the norms, thank you for that note.

Comment: We can assume that $f\in C[0,1]$, because in your definition, we have $x\in E$ (otherwise the notation $x_n\to x$ would not make sense). Note that in this example, the operator is defined on the whole space, not just on a subset $D(T)$.

Comment: Okay. Also you say: $||.||_1 \leq ||.||_2$ you mean $||.||_1 \leq ||.||_infty$ right?